# List of "live-editing" multi-user platforms (for web-site project)

Tags: javascript, php, html, github, collaborative-editing

(after a research in Google) I would like to know what are the options for collaborative (possibly LIVE) coding on HTML, CSS, javascript, Php documents.

I am new of Github, and as my understanding it does not allow LIVE editing to the documents, meaning that multiple people could work on a document on the same time creating inconsistencies.

Is this correct?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This seems off topic because it is asking for a software recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub is a repository hosting service. It's made for collaboration and has many nice and cool features, but I don't think it's made for this kind of collaboration you expect.

To use GitHub you need to set your project under version control, with `git` which is a version control system. So it's important to know, what do you **exactly** want?

A platform where you and your friends can edit some code (LIVE) but not in the course of a big project, or a platform where you can set-up a project, put it under version control and let your friends collaborate with you.